# Returning result for .net Web Api from db call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to the .net Web API and am trying to figure out how I return a Get result from a call to my database. I know everything works in my regular MVC page. But Not sure how to return the result from the Web API controller. I thought it was as simple as returning Json with the result. Here is my code:

```
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()

    {

        using (var _db = new JobsDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var user = Env.CurrentUser;
            var posts =
                _db.JobPostings.Where(
                    j =>
                        j.City.Equals(user.City, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                        j.Industry.ID == user.Industry.ID);
            var result = new List<BusJobPost>();

            foreach (var post in posts)
            {
                var p = new BusJobPost(post);
                result.Add(p);
            }

            return Json(result);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visit this resource: [Action Results in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results). 
Your case is described in fourth section *Some other type* (which is applicable to first version of Web API as well).

In Web API you don't return JSON result explicitly. It is actually done by process called *Content Negotiation*. You can read about it [here [Content Negotiation in ASP.NET Web API]](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) in detail.

Highlighting briefly just some of this:

- You can set Accept header for you request as: `Accept: application/json` (for example, if you use jquery ajax function: `dataType: 'json'`)
- Or even if you don't use Accept header at all, if you send request with JSON data, you should also get response back in JSON format

So you should just return `result` variable from your controller action and satisfy some of conditions to get response serialized into JSON.